# .htaccess redirect both naked http and https to www https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have similar issue on one of my domains. I have SSL cert installed both for naked and www-domain.

Now, however I want to redirect both naked http://domain.com and https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com.

I have this rules in my .htaccess, but it covers redirect when you visit site explicitly with https://domain.com, but, when visiting http://domain.com, it redirects to http://www.domain.com instead https://www.domain.com.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally would lay it out like this, this will force WWW and HTTPs for everything.

```
RewriteEngine On

#Force WWW on everything
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Force HTTPS on everything
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: If URL is `http://example.com` then this snippet will do two redirects and that is not good for both performance or SEO

Comment: Always learning, thanks for your input @anubhava. Will have to change my methods moving forward :P

Comment: Use https on the first rule and you avoid the double redirect. Never test with [`R=301`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your existing rule with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www and convert http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Keep this rule right below `RewriteEngine On` line and clear your browser cache before testing.